# Flutter Bloc state not updating

Tags: flutter, bloc

In the weather application, I am making an application that changes the theme color according to the weather conditions of the city. In the application, I want to change the theme with the data from the api, but the theme does not change. where is the problem? I'm not getting any errors either.
I use bloc 8.0.1

**Bloc**

```
  class ThemeBloc extends Bloc<ThemeEvent, ThemeState> {
  ThemeBloc() : super(ThemeApp(color: Colors.blue, theme: ThemeData.light())) {
    on<ThemeEvent>((event, emit) {
     if (event is ThemeChangeEvent) {
    ThemeApp? appTheme;

    switch (event.weatherStateAbbr) {
      case "sn": //karlı
      case "sl": //sulu kar
      case "h": //dolu
      case "t": //fırtına
      case "hc": //çok bulutlu
        appTheme = ThemeApp(
            theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey),
            color: Colors.grey);
        break;

      case "hr": //ağır yagmurlu
      case "lr": //hafif yagmurlu
      case "s": // sağanak yagıs
        appTheme = ThemeApp(
            theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.indigoAccent),
            color: Colors.indigo);
        break;

      case "lc": //az bulutlu
      case "c": //açık güneşli hava
        appTheme = ThemeApp(
            theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.orangeAccent),
            color: Colors.yellow);
        break;
    }
    emit(appTheme!);
    }
   });
  }
 }
```

**event**

```
  abstract class ThemeEvent extends Equatable {
   const ThemeEvent();

  @override
 List<Object> get props => [];
 }

 class ThemeChangeEvent extends ThemeEvent {
  final String weatherStateAbbr;

 const ThemeChangeEvent({required this.weatherStateAbbr});
}
```

**State**

```
 abstract class ThemeState extends Equatable {
 const ThemeState();

 @override
 List<Object> get props => [];
 }

 class ThemeApp extends ThemeState {
 final ThemeData theme;
 final MaterialColor color;

 const ThemeApp({required this.theme, required this.color});
}
```

** main.dart**

```
final locator = GetIt.instance;

 void setUp() {
 locator.registerLazySingleton<WeatherRepository>(() => 
  WeatherRepository());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => WeatherApiClient());
}

void main() {
 setUp();
 runApp(BlocProvider<ThemeBloc>(
 create: (context) => ThemeBloc(),
 child: const MyApp(),
  ));
 }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return BlocBuilder(
   bloc: BlocProvider.of<ThemeBloc>(context),
   builder: (context, ThemeState state) => MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'Weather App',
    theme: (state as ThemeApp).theme,
    home: BlocProvider<WeatherBloc>(
      create: (context) => WeatherBloc(),
      child: WeatherApp(),
    ),
  ),
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The concrete class also needs to override the props related to the Equatable package. Then put the objects into square brackets comma-separated.
Then the objects are compared from the Equatable package.

Event

```dart
abstract class ThemeEvent extends Equatable {
   const ThemeEvent();

  @override
 List<Object> get props => [];
 }

 class ThemeChangeEvent extends ThemeEvent {
  final String weatherStateAbbr;

 const ThemeChangeEvent({required this.weatherStateAbbr});

    List<Object> get props => [weatherStateAbbr];
}
```

State

```dart
abstract class ThemeState extends Equatable {
 const ThemeState();

 @override
 List<Object> get props => [];
 }

 class ThemeApp extends ThemeState {
 final ThemeData theme;
 final MaterialColor color;

 const ThemeApp({required this.theme, required this.color});

    List<Object> get props => [theme,color];
}
```

If two similar states occur one after the other, the bloc will not respond to that second state. If we take both states as the current and previous, the block does not respond to the current state.

Refer to this bloc documentation for more details.
[https://bloclibrary.dev](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/)

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still persists :/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call your event on your UI/Screen.

Call this line inside your initState `bloc.add(ThemeChangeEvent());`

```dart
class WeatherApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeatherApp();

  @override
  State<WeatherApp> createState() => _WeatherAppState();
}

class _WeatherAppState extends State<WeatherApp> {
  final ThemeBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of<ThemeBloc>(context);

  @override
  void initState() {
    bloc.add(ThemeChangeEvent());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    bloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

It's recommended to use statefulWidget because it has dispose and inistate. There is no problem as long as you are not using built in setState.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add equatable override in your child class like this and one of the item to the props , So in this if color changes the state will emit again with new data.

```
abstract class ThemeState extends Equatable {
 const ThemeState();

 @override
 List<Object> get props => [];
 }

 class ThemeApp extends ThemeState {
 final ThemeData theme;
 final MaterialColor color;

 const ThemeApp({required this.theme, required this.color});
 @override
 List<Object> get props => [color];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that sometimes a *const* widget will not get updated.

Simply remove the const keyword from the widget constructor. It will throw a warning, but it should be fine.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  // const removed
  MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

I've also experienced issues with BlocProviders not getting updated, so if your nested widget is child of another Bloc, it might not get updated if the root bloc updates.